# How to set up Pegasus Mail in non-admin account?

Tags: setup

I'm using Pegasus Mail for my mail client, and on my old computer (XP Pro), I could log in as the guest or admin account and it would still work.  I recently got a new computer, with XP Pro, and I've set the mail client to work fine when I log in to the admin account, but when I log into the guest account, it always wants the SMTP, POP, and other connection information.

How do I get it to remember that?  I tried making an admin account, setting it up, and then downgrading that account, but that didn't work either.   Does anyone even use PMail?

Comment: This seems to be the first pmail question here on su. Sorry that I can't help.

Comment: I used Pegasus Mail at university in the mid-'90s.  It must seem so old fashioned now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would look at would be the user permissions on the home mailbox location (you can find the location by going to Help -> About Pegasus Mail... and clicking the Info button).

If you set it up as the windows XP Admin, it probably has read/write/create permissions that the windows XP guest account doesn't.

Comment: My XP tells me to move it to the shared folder, but when I do so, it asks for a username on start up.  I don't know what that is.  I tried 'Admin' 'Administrator' '<default>' and 'cak' (one of my aliases), but nothing is working.  How do I know what my username is?  If I move it back to the c:\Pmail directory, it doesn't ask for a username.  (I'm the only user on the computer, but I'd like to not always be admin!)

Comment: I have a PMAIL.USR file and when I look at it, it has the following information:

; PMAIL.USR Pegasus Mail user database.
A;Admin;Mail Administrator

Comment: There is no reason not to run pmail as the pmail admin user. Pmail has its own idea of users which is not the same as the windows xp one.
Perhaps this will help:
http://www.vandenbogaerde.net/pegasusmail/pf_fromstomu.html